# Finding explicit formula for intersection of perpendicular bisectors of a triangle

Tags: geometry

Let $T= [p,q,s]$ be an arbitrary triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Without loss of generality,  one can assume that $s$ is the origin and that $q$ lies on the x axis,  say $q = (q1,0)$.  This will greatly simplify the calculations. Find the equation of the perpendicular bisectors of the three sides of this triangle. Show  that  these  three  lines  intersects  each  other  at  the  same  point.   Find  an explicit formula for this point and let us call it Q.

I know that I need to find 3 vector equations for the perpendicular bisectors and I've found the midpoint of all 3 vectors by adding the vectors and dividing by two. However I'm not sure how to find a solution for the direction vector for perpendicular bisector. I know the dot product of the direction vector and vector  along one side of the triangle must be 0 but that gives an infinite number of solutions how do I know which one to pick. And once I do have 3 vector equations how do I find formula for intersection?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle.

Comment: What expression are you using for vectors?  Possible expression $y=y_0+y_1t$ and $x=x_0+x_1t$.

Comment: Pick any one of them that’s convenient—they’re all multiples of the same vector.

Answer (score 1):

The direction vector for a perpendicular bisector (p.b.) is obviously perpendicular to the side.  For example, the p.b. of (s,q) is ((q1)/2,y) where y can be any value, so it is a line with equation x=(q1)/2. Similarly the other two have linear equations.  Two equations meet at a point.  Check that the third equation goes through the same point.

Comment: I get how you would to it in Cartesian coordinates, the slope of each perpendicular bisector would be -1/m if m is the slope of the side of the triangle. However I'm supposed to do this question with vectors so how would this work in that regard?